# Html emails <hr/> styling issue

Tags: html, email, outlook, styles

I have a problem with e-mail clients reverting my styled `<hr/>` to one with just a solid line.

The following is my mark-up, looks fine in Chrome and IE but Outlook always reverts the dotted line to a solid one.

```
<hr style="background:none; border:dotted 1px #999999; border-width:1px 0 0 0; height:0; width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;" ></hr>
```

I have looked at Campaign Monitor but nothing particular to guide me there.

All answers appreciated.

Comment: I've retagged Outlook, but is it a particular version of Outlook? 2007 onwards, perhaps?

Comment: all e-mail clients really, but 2003 and 2007 are the one's I'm looking at.

Comment: is outlook being even more evil than IE have always been for websites ? And is OUTLOOK 2013 even worst than all the previous versions ?!!!

Answer (score 32):

I would imagine it's because outlook uses the Microsoft word rendering engine, rather than a HTML engine, and a hr tag would just get reverted to a solid line as in msword.

I'd probably try using a full width table->cell or div and style that instead of using an hr tag.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background:none; border:dotted 1px #999999; border-width:1px 0 0 0; height:1px; width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**nbsp** is in there in case the rendering engine doesn't recognise empty cells.

Comment: i also realise that this isn't probably the most elegant way to code it.

Comment: Thanks Kolin, but it actually work. I;d tried the same technique to limited effect. I have added the solution below which is, in your own words, rather inelegant

Comment: Don't bother with the hr tag unless you want the default colors and margins that Outlook/Word uses.

Comment: This is the only `<hr>` alternative i've found to work in all clients.

Comment: Everone complaining about elegance in html for emails misses the point that coding for email has nothing to do with computational nor mathematical thinking; also it tends to get rather really ugly.

Comment: This worked great for me after setting border etc. to zero. <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> Thanks!

Comment: This gives me a box of 1-2 line heights, surrounded by a dotted line in Outlook 2010 / Win7 (probably other Outlook versions, too). :(

Comment: @SirBenBenji what exactly is the point? Just because it *can* get ugly doesn't mean we shouldn't strive to make it as clear as we can.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the other answers, I found this to work best:

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:none; border-bottom: 1px solid #d7dfe3; height:1px; width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
```

The width seems to be needed on `table` in % or preferrably (as per https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/) set it in `px` on the `td` if possible.

The `border-bottom` shorthand seems to work fine, where the *longhand* versions as mentioned in kolin's answer don't in Outlook.

EDIT: What I found to have used previously and also works, at least in Outlook (would be nice if anyone who can, could test that in other clients), is a `<hr>`based approach.

```
<hr height="1" style="height:1px; border:0 none; color: #D7DFE3; background-color: #D7DFE3; margin-top:1.5em; margin-bottom:1.5em;">
```

Comment: The <hr> approach works well on the GMail web client too, as well as latest Outlook desktop client as of 2020 (not sure of the version number these days).

Answer (score 4):

Rather inelegant and only useful for a known fixed width but I'm finding that these are the terrors visited upon you when trying to fix formatting in html emails'.

```
<p style="line-height:20%; color:#cccccc; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">........................................................................................................................................</p>
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm having to use something like this to get dotted borders in outlook *sigh*

Comment: The p tag isn't easy to control in all email clients, and several of them (outlook.com) don't recognize margin/padding on the p tag, so I don't suggest using this solution.

Comment: hahaha this made me laugh out loud. Good one. I'll give it a +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use this example:

```
<div style="border-top: 1px dotted #999999;">&nbsp;</div>
```

It will only work against white background unfortunately

Comment: @dude this question is regarding Outlook email HTML parsing not mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Need to declare a font-size, otherwise " " messes with the height.

```
 <tr><td style="background:none; border-bottom: 4px solid #DC1431; height:1px; width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```