# Need to fix horizontal line in email signature

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm creating an email signature using CodeTwo Email signature from Office 365. It's nearly done, but I keep having issues with a horizontal line that's in the signature. I've tried multiple variations of CSS style elements to get it to work everywhere, but as of now, it shows up on mobile devices, but not desktop devices (it shows up as like an outline of the line on desktop). For the longest time, it worked on desktop but not mobile, but then when I changed something it flipped. I'm using an hr element for the line. Here's a segment of the code:

```
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 350px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD 
    style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px; COLOR: #213e64" 
    vAlign=top><STRONG>{First name} {Last name}</STRONG></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px" 
      vAlign=top>{Title}</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 400px" vAlign=top>
      <HR 
      style="BORDER-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 3px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; WIDTH: 80%; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline-block; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #213e64" 
      align=left>
    </TD></TR>
```

Does anyone know what combination of stylings I would need in my `hr` tag?  Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html emails <hr/> styling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206252/html-emails-hr-styling-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `<hr>` try using a `<div>` with a `border-bottom` of the required size:

`<div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #213e64;"></div>`

#### Example

```html
<table style="WIDTH: 350px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px; COLOR: #213e64" vAlign=top>
        <strong>{First name} {Last name}</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px" vAlign=top>{Title}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 400px" vAlign=top>
        <div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #213e64;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked on mobile, but not on desktop, plus it fit too tightly into the next element (which is a logo), so they combined together.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the HR tag and have some styles that are not needed, try this

```html
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 350px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD 
    style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px; COLOR: #213e64" 
    vAlign=top><STRONG>{First name} {Last name}</STRONG></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 350px" 
      vAlign=top>{Title}</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; WIDTH: 400px" vAlign=top>
      <HR 
      style="HEIGHT: 3px; WIDTH: 80%;  DISPLAY: inline-block; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #213e64" 
      align=left />
    </TD></TR>
    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: It almost works on mobile, but I get a thin grey line on top of the blue line and a thin white line on the bottom of the line. On desktop, the blue of the line doesn't even show up, but you can see a sort of outline of the line

Comment: Which browser and mobile you using to test this

Comment: checked it on safari and chrome on MacBook and iPhone and it works well, please share your screenshots